# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> error question

Tags: c#

I have the following code, but i`m having error of

> Error 6 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' C:\Dev\DEV\Code\MvcUI\Models\MappingModel.cs 100 13 MvcUI

### How can I solve this?

Note:

```
string [] projectID;


    Class Project
    {
        int id {get; set;}
        string Name {get;set;}
    }
```

---

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStudents()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var id in Convert.ToInt32(projectID))
        {
            foreach( Project project in Project.Load(id))
                result.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected =  false,
                    Text = emp.ID.ToString(),
                    Value = emp.Name
                });

            return result.AsEnumerable();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where in the code does the error occur? Also, can you clean up the code?

Comment: Do you really mean to return from the body of the outer loop? It will only run for a single iteration and is therefore mainly pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Your tring to convert the strings in projectId to int in the foreach statement. Put the convert inside the foreach.

Try this

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStudents()
{
    List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var id in projectID)
    {
        int intId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        foreach( Employee emp in Project.Load(intId))
            result.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected =  false,
                Text = emp.ID.ToString(),
                Value = emp.Name
            });
    }
    return result.AsEnumerable();
}
```

There are other problems. You are returning from inside the loop so you are only ever going to get this to work for the first id. I tried to correct that in the above code

Comment: Yes this would work, didnt see the line string[] projectID.

By the way, why is string[] projectId a collection of strings? and not a collection of int[]?

Comment: I have tried the code, but i`m having the error
Error 6 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type Employee' because 'Employee' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' C:\Dev\DEV\Code\MvcUI\Models\MappingModel.cs 103 17 MvcUI on the second foreach loop

Comment: @user281180 - What does `Project.Load(int id)` return? A single employee? or a project with employees? If it is a project with employees the line should look like `foreach(Employee emp in Project.Load(intId).Employees)` but you might want to watch out for null.

Comment: It returns an employee, I would prefer to write it as follows to avoid confusion:
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStudents() 
{ 
    List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
    foreach (var id in projectID) 
    { 
        int intId = Convert.ToInt32(id); 
        foreach( Project project in Project.Load(intId)) 
            result.Add(new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Selected =  false, 
                Text = project.ID.ToString(), 
                Value = project.Name 
            }); 
    } 
    return result.AsEnumerable(); 
}

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `projectID` is a `string[]` and you're trying to convert it to a `int[]`.  If so you can do the following to make the foreach loop work

```
foreach (var id in projectID.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get each value from projectID and convert it to an integer and use each converted value for project.load().  How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt32(projectID) would not return a collection of ints, it would return a single Int instance, therefore you cannot use a foreach statement for it.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get each value from projectID and convert it to an integer and use each converted value for project.load(). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStudents()
{
    return from id in projectID
           from employee in Project.Load(int.Parse(id))
           select new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = employee.ID.ToString(),
               Value = employee.Name
           };
}
```

Remark: your naming conventions are a little strange: GetStudents using Project.Load which returns employees.